# GmapPanel Can't zoomLevel - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.tree.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    'Ext.window.*',
    'Ext.ux.GMapPanel'
]);

var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                //renderTo: 'layout',
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight,
                //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
                layout: 'border',
                items: [{
                    title: 'Message List',
                    region: 'south',     // position for region
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height: 100,
                    split: true,         // enable resizing
                    collapsible: true,
                    margins: '0 5 5 5',
                    collapsed: true
                },tree,{
                    //title: 'Map',
                    region: 'center',     // center region is required, no width/height specified
                    xtype: 'gmappanel',
                    mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
                    mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],   
                    zoomLevel: 2,
                    gmapType: 'map'
                }],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
            });
```

[image]

### Question

how come my code can't zoom,gmaptype with map and small map? even set center with x,y coordinate also can't work.please help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to add

```
    setCenter: {
        'lat': 37.4419,
        'lng': -122.1419,
        marker:{ title: 'Palo Alto'}
    }
```

in xtype:'gmappanel'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing same problem, i solved this by changing zoom in `GMapPanel.js` in the following code section :

```
options = Ext.applyIf(options, {
        zoom: 4,         // <-- change this to whatever you want
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });
```

Note: I did'nt added the above code to `GMapPanel.js`, it is already there, just find it and change zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = Ext.applyIf(options, {
    zoom: this.zoom || 14,      // FIX 
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});
```

use the var zoom when creating the xtype to change the default zoom value

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do. You need to include the 'zoomLevel' in a 'mapOptions' object. Here's an example:

```
xtype: 'gmappanel',
height: 300,
width: 300,
mapOptions: {
    zoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    //...etc
}
```